Export of JPEG XL (.jxl) files with current GIMP not possible but should be since version 2.10.34
since version 2.10.34 GIMP does support export of JPEG XL files.
https://www.gimp.org/news/2023/02/27/gimp-2-10-34-released/
But when I try to export as .jxl, I am getting the message about unknown file extension.
Using GIMP 2.10.38, installed and updated from Ubuntu Snap, with Ubuntu 22.04.1. Why is that so, is .jxl not implemented yet in the Ubuntu version?

Ubuntu 22.04.1 is not a fully updated version. Start with a sudo apt update and a sudo apt upgrade and try again.

Is you GIMP the Ubuntu packaged or isntalled via snap? The GIMP plugin would require JPEG XL libraries in the system - maybe the Ubuntu packagers did not change the build requirements to include these libs and GIMP is built without support for it.

My GIMP is the apt package version 2.10.36 in Ubuntu 24.04. It can open and edit .jxl files. It can also convert files from .jpg to .jxl and export them. To export a .jpg file as .jxl just change the file's extension to .jxl when you export it and GIMP will understand that. Alternatively when exporting the image with Export As… you can click the printed text where it says Select File Type (By Extension) in the lower left corner of the Export Image window and select JPEG XL image from the dropdown menu.
The file manager even shows the thumbnails of the exported .jxl images.
The upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 is not recommended for very good reasons until the first point release of Ubuntu 24.04 is released in another two weeks.
